# splitting angular code in to different components

Tags: angular, input, components

I have two input fields on my page. one is  email type and the other one is a input field with text.

everything is working fine. Now I want to split the component into two .
eg. i have a 'basic-info' component now. i want a 'text' component inside basic-info component and move the text code to it.
input.html

```
 <app-text *ngIf="info.type === 'text'"></app-text>
<input *ngIf="info.type === 'email'" type="text" [formControlName]="controlName" />
```

input.ts

```
public info: InputInterface;
```

text.html

```
<input *ngIf="info.type === 'text'" type="text" [formControlName]="controlName" />
```

text.ts

```
public info: InputInterface;
```

the error i am getting is in autocomplete.ts type is undefined.
I think I need to pass the property from the parent component(input) to the child component (text). I am new to angular and not able to figure this out. I tried @Input directive but still the error is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you declare an input in a child component, you need to pass a value to it via the parent HTML file. Since you're not passing 'info' in the parent.html, you're getting that error. Here's the right way:

text.ts

```js
@Input() public info: InfoInterface;
```

text.html

```html
<input *ngIf="info.type === 'text'" type="text"/>
```

parent.html (Note that *ngIf isn't compulsory here. It was present in your code, so I added it here too assuming it's your requirement)

```html
<app-text [info]="parentInfoToBePassed" *ngIf="parentInfoToBePassed.type === 'text'"></app-text>
```

parent.ts

```js
public parentInfoToBePassed: InfoInterface = {type: 'text'};
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-input-example
This is a simple example for how to split your code and use Inputs.

Hope this helps. Let me know if anything isn't clear

Comment: what if there are more than one data in the interface. like type, label, defaultvalue and the values are dynamic

Comment: Since I didn't know the exact structure of InfoInterface, I wrote only type: 'text', but you can add all the other fields too. That entire object will be passed to info in text.ts. So in text.html, you will have access to info.label, info.defaultValue etc

Comment: cant I use this is parent .public info: InputInterface; and then in the parent.html [info]="info"

Comment: Sure, you can! You wont get any conflicts as they are in different files. I just wrote it that way to make it easy to understand.